# How long it takes to publish a script in Script Gallery

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

When will the script get published in Script Gallery, that I submitted from Google Spreadsheet Script editor?

And at the time of submitting the script, it displayed message "Your project has been sent for approval and we will send you a separate email when it is approved. Your project ID is xxxxxxxxxxxxx. Please reference this ID in any future communications with us. Thank you for using Google Apps Script."

So, with whom shall I communicate regarding it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally my script got published after seven days or so, but I still haven't got any notification regarding it....
So if anyone else has the same question then this answer might help..!

Comment: Useful to know, but a shame their process is so obfuscated.